# Diseño de BD - Sistema de facturación

Tags: mysql, base-de-datos, diagrama-de-flujo

Tengo un problema con el diseño de algunas tablas de una base de datos. 
La aplicación vendría a ser un sistema de facturación en el cual el stock no es importante, sino más bien controlar la cantidad de ventas realizadas. Utilizando MySQL Workbench (***gracias a un usuario de esta comunidad que me lo sugirió***) pude entablar las siguientes relaciones:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

### Explicación breve de las tablas

- **Ciclo**: 
  corresponde a un ciclo de venta; un producto puede variar su precio según el ciclo en el que se encuentre (los ciclos normalmente van del 1 al 12 y corresponden a los meses del año).
- **Categoría**: 
  un producto debe tener al menos una categoría y puede o no tener una
  subcategoría. El principal problema radica acá: me sugirieron
  utilizar recursividad, pero el "puede o no tener un subcategoría" no
  sé como expresarlo, ya que la clave foránea (idcategoría -> categoría
  padre) no puede estar vacía.
- **Producto**:
  abstracción de un producto. Solo los campos que no varían de ciclo a ciclo se plasman en esta tabla.
- **Producto_Ciclo**:
  es la relación de un producto en un ciclo particular. Creo que las tablas precio_promocional, comisión_vendedor y cannon las debería modificar ya que no son calculadas (y precio_promocional me daría problemas más adelante).
- **Vendedor**:
  tabla que detalla los datos de un vendedor.
- **Cliente**:
  tabla que detalla los datos de un cliente.
- **Detalle**:
  relaciona cada 'venta' realizada por el sistema.
- **Factura**:
  relaciona todas las ventas realizadas por el sistema para un cliente específico según un vendedor.

### En fin, mis dudas/problemas/preguntas:

1. ¿Cómo resolver el tema de las categorías/subcategorías?
2. ¿Existe una mejor forma (*se que existe, nada más quisiera saberla*) de recrear los productos según un ciclo específico sin tener que crear la tabla 'producto_ciclo'?

**Nota**: se que es engorroso que un vendedor sea a la vez un usuario, pero por ahora no me interesa tanto recrear una tabla 'usuario' y relacionarla con la tabla 'vendedor'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No corresponde con las preguntas que has realizado pero pienso que las tablas 'cliente' y 'vendedor' podrían ser la especialización de una tabla general llamada -por ejemplo- 'persona' que contenga las columnas comunes, así mismo, las direcciones de las redes sociales deberían estar contenidas en otra tabla que se relacione con la tabla 'persona'.

Respecto a la tabla 'producto_ciclo', es la tabla de lista de precios, o yo la llamaría así, claro, los precios pueden variar según los periodos de venta, generándose en consecuencia versiones de lista de precios. La tabla 'detalle' debería relacionarse con la tabla 'producto' y no con la tabla 'producto_ciclo' (que reitero yo la llamaría 'lista_precios'), en un ejercicio de venta -posterior a seleccionar el producto- es fácil recuperar el precio consultando con la tabla 'producto_ciclo' cuyo único objetivo es contener los precios vigentes e históricos, es una tabla de consulta.

Respecto a la relación entre las tablas 'producto' y 'categoría', se entiende que almacenas -en la tabla 'producto'- la referencia del último nodo de una rama, la misma que podría incluir "n" nodos precedentes que lógicamente no necesitas almacenarlos porque puedes navegar hacia ellos mediante la relación recursiva, no veo el problema.

Comment: ¡Gracias por todos los consejos! En si, tenia planeado los datos comunes en otras tablas (en vez de llamarse persona, era datos_persona, pero en si cumplen la misma función). Y me sirve muchísimo lo que comentaste y tus opiniones para seguir diseñando mejor está BD. Con respecto a la categoría me surge la necesidad de poder agregar una categoría que no contenga subcategoría. Esto no sucede en el diseño que recree, ya que la fk apunta si o si a la pk de la misma tabla. Esa era mi duda.

Comment: ¿Por qué la columna 'categoria_padre' tiene la restricción NOT NULL?, ¿tienes algún sustento?. En una estructura jerárquica los nodos de primer nivel (nivel de profundidad cero) no tienen precedentes, en consecuencia la columna 'categoria_padre' -para la fila "parent"- es NULL.